# Maven : Excluding src/main/webapp/resources from the WAR is not working

Tags: maven-war-plugin

I have **src** and **src_backup** directories that are identical except that I have created src_backup from src by renaming (*cache busting purpose*) all the .js and .css files in

> src/main/webapp/resources
>    directory.

I am using **maven-war-plugin 2.4**. I want the WAR file to include renamed files from

> src_backup/main/webapp/resources

and exclude original files from

> src/main/webapp/resources

I am able to include from src_backup but cannot exclude from src. What I end up getting is the WAR file containing both versions of files (original ones as well as renamed ones). I have read more than 5 different sources (such as stackoverflow) and tried more than 20 different ways to do so but it does not work.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>targetWAR</warName>
                <warSourceExcludes>/${baseDir}/src/main/webapp/resources</warSourceExcludes>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src_backup/main/webapp/resources</directory>
                        <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src_backup/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/views</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I have also tried to use resources tag in the build tag but did not work.

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

I am sure I am missing something. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: In sort, I want to exclude entire src/main/webapp directory and include src_backup/main/webapp directory

Answer (score 0):

You could change `warSourceDirectory`, see [warSourceDirectory in war mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warSourceDirectory). For instance:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src_backup/main/webapp/resources</warSourceDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See also my answer to rename files, and not use different directories: [Renaming static files when building WAR file using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859421/renaming-static-files-when-building-war-file-using-maven)